# expanding center of 3 floating divs to fit width of parent container div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div, with 3 inner divs that are floated. The left and right divs are statically sized, but I would like the center div to expand to the fit the parent container.

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center">this should expand to fit the parent container</div>
    <div class="right"></div>
<div>

.parent-container
{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid pink;
}

.left { width: 50px; }
.right { width: 80px; }

.left, .center, .right
{ 
    float: left; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    height: 100px; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fvuyQ/

I have tried setting the width to 100%, but that doesn't work. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK with using CSS3 you can use the `calc()` function coupled with `box-sizing: border-box`

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/4usMS/

**Note:** The reason why I added `box-sizing: border-box` was to make it easier to calculate the center div's width. If you don't want `box-sizing: border-box` you can substract the sum of the widths of the left and right borders on the floating divs, which amounts to a total of 6px, like this:

`.center { width: calc(100% - 50px - 80px - 6px); }`

**Edit:** Updated the example to use CSS2 positioning instead of CSS3 `calc()` http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/4usMS/1

Comment: this seems like a nice solution, but i do need compatibility across most browsers (excluding maybe ie6)

Comment: Well, you can use positioning, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/4usMS/1/

Comment: i have accepted this as the answer as it doesn't require padding on the center div to adjust the text, and the answer could be tested in the supplied jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

How about only floating the left/right elements and giving margins to the center one

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="center">this should expand to fit the parent container</div>
<div>
```

css

```
.left { width: 50px;float: left; }
.right { width: 80px;float: right; }
.center{border:1px solid green;margin:0 80px 0 50px;}
.left, .right
{ 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    height: 100px; 
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/fvuyQ/4/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your css

```
.center { 
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%; //add this if you always want it to be 100% of the parent
}

.left, .right, .center {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

you probably should also add this

```
.parent-container {
     float: left;
     display: block;
     position: relative;
}
```

Also, if I'm understanding your question correctly, you might want something like this

```
.right, .left { position: absolute; }
.right { top: 0; right: 0; }
.left { top: 0; left: 0; }
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the text in the center div floats to the top left of the parent container

Comment: then add .center { padding: 0 10%; } change the percent to whatever works or use pixels.  And in all honesty, your code would be better off by adding more divs. Like a wrapper or three.

Comment: can you please update the http://jsfiddle.net/fvuyQ/3/ to explain what you mean by more divs? it already has your changes in it